# applescript to unlock mac works very slow

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, unlock

Hello i am using this script to unlock the mac

```
tell me to activate\n
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"PASSWORD\"\n 
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return\n 
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return"
```

the problem is it is very very slow and it take time between 3-10 seconds
 randomly to unlock the MAC. i want to do it in 1-2 seconds.i have search a lot but didnt find any good script if any one know please guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: The code as written does not compile!  What version of OS X and how are you invoking the script?

Comment: Dear i am using the latest one 10.10.3

Answer (score 1):

I'm parking this here as a placeholder so I don't forget what I wrote - still needs clarification from the OP

To tidy up your existing script - you don't need to tell 'me' to activate, it already must be frontmost to work at all.

```
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "PASSWORD"
        keystroke return
        keystroke return
    end tell
```

To do it from scratch, though idk how you would call this before login

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "loginwindow" to entire contents

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "loginwindow"
        tell window "Login Panel"
            if name of static text 1 is "username" then
                set value of text field 1 to "password"
                keystroke return
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
```

Comment: Hello @Tetsujin i have tried the following script but no luck there is no improvement in speed factor . can you please tell me what should be the reason for this.

Comment: actually it doesn't work either